# tar a specific number of files listed in a text file

Tags: tar

I have a text file which contains a list of files.

I use.

```
tar --null --no-recursion -uf abc.tar --directory= /tmp/temp --files-from abc.txt
```

This command simply creates a tar with all the files listed in the text file.

Is there any way where I can tar only selected number of files from the list? Say for example only first 50 files listed in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like: (**Updated to allow for whitespaces in file names**)

```
head -50 abc.txt | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 tar --null -no-recursion -uf abc.tar --directory=/tmp/temp
```

The command `head -50` will get you the first 50 lines of the list file. This result is piped `|` to `tr`. Basically, `tr` will perform a translation operation, replacing the  newline characters `\n` by a null character `\0`. The result is piped to `xargs -0`, which will convert all these lines into arguments to the `tar` command.
The `-0` arguments for `xargs` makes it separate the arguments based on null characters instead of white spaces. This will make the command works even if your file names has spaces.

Thanks to Jordanm for his comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `head` or `tail` to control the number of files that you're limiting from the file `abc.txt`.

#### Example

Sample `abc.txt` file.

```
$ cat abc.txt
afile1
afile10
afile2
afile3
afile4
afile5
afile6
afile7
afile8
afile9
```

Now we'll tar only the 1st 3 files from `abc.txt`:

```
$ head -3 abc.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | tar --null --no-recursion -uf abc.tar -T -
```

The above takes the output from `head ...`, converts the end of line characters (`\n`) to null characters (`\0`). This output is then piped to tar, which takes it in through STDIN, (`-T -`). This last bit tells `tar` to take STDIN as input, this is the list of file names to `tar`.

Confirmation of `abc.tar`:

```
$ tar tvf abc.tar 
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml         0 2013-08-05 13:24 afile1
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml         0 2013-08-05 13:24 afile10
-rw-rw-r-- saml/saml         0 2013-08-05 13:24 afile2
```

You can change the above from `head -3 ...` to head -100 ...`for example, to get the 1st 100. Or you could use`tail -100 ...` to get the last 100 in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by jordanm's comment on Bichoy's answer, here's how you can deal with file names with spaces in them:

```
count=50
i=1
while [ $i -le $count ]
do
    read filename
    tar --null -no-recursion -ruf abc.tar "$filename" --directory=/tmp/temp
    i=$(($i+1))
done <abc.txt
```

I used a `while` loop instead of doing `for i in {1..50}` in order to allow you to soft-code the number of lines required.

Comment: In my scenario , the files are seperated using ^@ and i need to tar only certain number of files . is there any command for that in linux? cause i have to do it through java

Comment: @user1752557 Do you mean a literal '^' followed by a literal '@' or the control character '^@'?

Comment: @user1752557 As for doing it in Java, can you not make a Linux system all from Java? (I'm not that experienced with it so I'm not really certain).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there are no newlines in your file names, convert the null bytes to newlines and call `head` to retain only the first few lines.

```
<abc.txt tr '\0' '\n' |
head -n 50 |
tar --null --no-recursion -uf abc.tar --directory= /tmp/temp --files-from -
```

To cope with filenames containing newlines, you can transpose newlines and nulls, then let `head` to its stuff, and transpose back.

```
<abc.txt tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
head -n 50 |
tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
tar --null --no-recursion -uf abc.tar --directory= /tmp/temp --files-from -
```