# Split the content of a file in linux

Tags: files, text-processing

I have a text file which has content like this:

```
abc.tar^@xxx.tar^@yyy.tar^@
```

Say for example I have this content in a file named `abc.txt` and I want to split the content and write the first two entries into a new file.

(e.g), the new file would look like this:

```
abc.tar^@xxx.tar^@
```

Is there any command to perform this operation?

Comment: are those the two characters `^` and `@`? Or the NUL character (`^@` aka `\0`).

Comment: In such case my awk goes (I think): awk -F"\x00" '{print $1"\x00"$2"x00"}' abc.txt > newfile.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this question is related to [that one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85523/tar-a-specific-number-of-files-listed-in-a-text-file/85530#85530), correct?

In that case, wouldn't replacing the '^@' with a newline be more worth your while?
In the following, I'm guessing you mean '^@', the ASCII NUL byte:

```
$ sed 's/\o000/\n/g' abc.txt | head -n 2
abc.tar
xxx.tar
```

So you need

```
sed 's/\o000/\n/g' abc.txt | head -n 2 > newfile.txt
```

**Explanation**

This substitutes a newline (`\n`) for every NUL byte (`\o000`) the `\o` part means that what follows is a byte in octal notation. The output is then piped to `head -n 2` which extracts the first two lines; and the resulting lines are redirected (`>`) to the file `newfile.txt`.

If it's important to you that the file names be separated by '^@', however, you can use this:

```
perl -nl000 -e '
    $num_lines =2 ;
    push @a,(split /\000/)[0..$num_lines-1];
    print $_ for @a' abc.txt > newfile.txt
```

Replace the value of `$num_lines` above as needed to grab the first `$num_lines` lines from the file.

**Explanation**

- The `-n` switch tells `perl` to run the code on each line of the input file
- The `-l000` sequence tells `perl` to set the output record separator
  (the character printed after every string) to the NUL byte (`000`).
- The `-e` switch tells `perl` that the string that follows is a code to execute.
- The `split` function splits each input line with the NUL byte as delimiter,takes the first `$num_lines` (`[0..$num_lines-1]`) results and puts them into the array `@a`. Notice that the "current input line" part is nowhere specified in the function call. This makes use of the fact that the default scalar variable in Perl (`$_`) is the default argument of the `split` function (among others) when no argument is supplied.
- The final `foreach` loop prints every element in `@a` (again note how `$_` is the default iterator for the `foreach` loop). Since we have set the output record separator to octal `000`, we get the results separated by the NUL byte as before.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph R , But can you pls tell me how can i use the command in through java?? since i need to pass it in double quotes like "sed 's/\o000/\n/g' abc.txt | head -n 2 > newfile.txt"   its showing error for the sequences.

Comment: @user1752557 What errors do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Is this:

```
awk -F"@" '{print $1"@"$2"@"}' abc.txt > newfile.txt
```

good enough for you?

Comment: The question is about records separated by null bytes, not by `@` characters.

Comment: Copying my own comment:  
In such case my awk goes (I think): awk -F"\x00" '{print $1"\x00"$2"\x00"}' abc.txt > newfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
sed -r -i 's/^(.*)@.*@.*$/\1/' file
```

Comment: What are you trying to match with `(.*)(.*)`? Also why use `cat`? You can do `sed -r 'pattern_here' file` directly. Finally, this code seems to assume that the input file only has 3 file names of which you extract the first one only.

Comment: `.*` should match on anything, the idea is to split the contents of the file using `@` as a delimiter.  And why **not** use `cat`--it's just as viable a method as any other.

Comment: My point is, `(.*)(.*)` will not yield any different result from `(.*)` why did you repeat it? As for why not use `cat`, it's not about functionality, it's about tacking on unneeded complexity. This is not what `cat` was made for anyway.

Comment: I think that I may have forgotten to try the above without the extra `(.*)` and so that may be why there's an extra one.  If you wish, feel free to edit the above.

Comment: Done. I'm leaving the `cat` up to your discretion :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Perl:

```
$ perl -ne '@F = split(/@/,$_); print "$F[1]\@$F[2]@";' abc.txt > newfile.txt
```

The above does the following:

- `@F = split(/@/,$_)` - splits the contents of file `abc.txt` a line  at a time up based on the character `@` and stores the resulting chunks in an array (`@F`).
- `print "$F[1]\@$F[2]@"` - prints the first 2 columns, (1 & 2), from array `@F` and inserts a at sign (`@`) in between each column.

Answer (score 0):

Awk can use any character as the record separator (with newline as the default), except that some implementations don't support the null byte as the separator. Gawk (GNU awk), the default awk on most non-embedded Linux installations, supports nulls.

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' 'NR <= 2 {print}'
```

This can be shortened to `gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' 'NR <= 2'` since printing the record is the default action.

For a large file, you'd better quit after the second line.

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' 'NR==3 {exit} {print}'
```

Alternatively, you can use `head`. There's no option to use a null byte instead of a newline as the record separator, but you can swap the two characters, call `head`, and then swap back.

```
tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head -n 2 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'
```